# Galaxy Tab 3 won't boot - dead battery?

Tags: battery

I'm kind of disappointed, this morning I wanted to start my GT3 but I get this logo instead (sorry for the poor quality) :

[image: Battery Logo]

I've try AB testing with my Nexus 5 battery loader, both works on my Nexus. The GT3 flash sometimes and boot a few times but stop after less than 1 min.

I can't launch the tests (<kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Vol +</kbd>) because it "needs battery to be above 3.4V.

Is the battery dead ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried powering it off and charging it for 6 hours? If not, that should be your first course of action. If after charging it still doesn't power on, you may have either a bad charger or a dead battery (or some other strange bug I've never run into). If you have a different charger, give that a go for 6 hours and see what changes.

On my Galaxy Note 10.1 I've had that logo show up when I have very low battery. It won't actually power on until the battery is partially charged once you've taken the battery all the way down to zero.

Also, youtube: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEQQtwIwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dl1jrrVcQ8f8&ei=3HPSU9LIOIqiyASgmoCwDw&usg=AFQjCNH9B0sbXK8q_fWhhpNVUnHmlmcXxg&sig2=lVcDHD3B7ilruFW4gPiMQA&bvm=bv.71667212,d.aWw

Comment: "It won't actually power on until the battery is partially charged."  With Android devices I've used, the minimum battery level to power on is 15%; lower than that, and you risk damaging the lithium cells, so the devices are programmed to shut down or refuse to start.

Answer (score 1):

After reading all the posts I tried to open the unit, but without luck.  I then thought my computer USB port may be 3.4v or more, so I plugged in the Galaxy 10.1 in the USB port, waited about 20 minutes tried turning on the unit and walla it was charging.  I did not see this fix noted anywhere in the posts and it may just be coincidental that it worked, but does not hurt to give it a try yourself....so glad I did not have to fool with the inside of my tablet.

Comment: This amounts to letting the device charge to 15% before booting.  It's a pretty nearly universal Android solution; after a low-power shutdown, or a long time unused, you'll need to let it charge for a while (20 minutes or more) before it'll boot.  Recommended you power off and let it charge overnight, then verify the device's charger is working correctly.  Chargers aren't expensive...

Comment: Great solution! Yes, let it charge some time before attempting to switch it on.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this [forum](http://www.phonandroid.com/forum/galaxy-tab-2-gt-p5210-ne-s-allume-plus-t93934.html) (in french, thanks god I'm french).

Your battery is too low, chances are you've left you tablet discharged and unused for quite a while.

Anyways, you need to unconnect the middle connector on top of you battery (you can see it in practice in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=humtforaj2w) then reconnect it and it should work again.

I'm amazed Samsung left such hardware bug in its device (Planned obsolescence?) but that's how it is.

Good luck